# Using VBA to loop through a query and outputting results

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So what I have here is a query that displays a Baseball players Name, Salary, and then shows normal baseball stats such as Hits, RBIs, etc. What I want to is have the code create a query at the end that will contain the player's name and and the result of an expression that looks like

```
 IIf([H]<>0,Format(([Salary]/[H]),'$#,###.##'),0) AS Per_H
```

I basically want to be able to make it apply that formula to every column after their name and salary.

Right now I have

```
Table  PlayerSal
NAME SALARY H R HR
```

With H being Hits, R being Runs, and HR being Homeruns.
My resulting query that I want should look like this.

```
 Player_Per

NAME Per_H, Per_R, Per_HR.
```

What exactly do I need to do?

Edit

I should add, yes, I know I can just input that very same function for each stat that I want to calculate it for, that isn't the point. I am trying to expand my knowledge while applying it to something that I find interesting. However, I know that this could probably be expanded to other things down the road.

Comment: You don't want to just do this in the query itself? You can use iif() in a query, you shouldn't need to use VBA

Comment: Well yes, if I was just doing this in a small amount, but then going through tons of stats in using a query takes time, especially when I will then go through and do the same thing to multiple sports. So that is highly inefficient.

Comment: I don't see how iterating a recordset in VBA is going to be any faster. It's going to be doing the same thing regardless.

Comment: Lets say I am doing something like this for 40 stats.. not that I can think of 40 stats , but either way, it shouldn't be that hard to creat some VBA that would basically create a variable that would fit into the Name of the columnn and then indicate to go after all records after the fact and apply that same formula to each column. Although..I don't have the knowledge to do so and I have tried looking it up.

Comment: And besides, efficiency aside, My question still remains.

Comment: Well I'll just throw something your way that I would do. `Select name, salary, h, iif(h<>0, format(salary/h,"currency")) as yourcalc FROM yourTable` just as a regular old vba-free query

Comment: Yes, I already have that, thanks. But I was going for the VBA route that would do it all without me having to manually put that in for every single field I want to apply it to.

Comment: @Chris, it sounds like you want to make an 'elegant` query that is free from all these pesky details which are hidden away in a custom VBA function. It's a good goal, but not always worthwhile. Try this: Just make a 'formatting layer' query that has all this ugly code in it.  Then make other queries that pull from this 'formatting layer' query. THESE queries will be clean and simple like you want.

Comment: Hmm... I will look into that.. although I have no idea what it is. Thanks for your helpful direction.

Comment: @Scotch I think you should post your comment as an answer. It is indeed "correct", even if it's not what the asker [thinks that he] wants.

Comment: I don't even really need anything elegant overall, I just really need something that will work without having to brute force it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, brother.  Last shot.  This code works.  However, it needs a small tweak because it doesn't loop through all the records.

```
Public Function HitTest()

Dim db As Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("tblPlayers")
EditTable = "tblPlayers"

For Each fld In rec.Fields
  If fld.Name <> "PName" And fld.Name <> "Salary" And Left(fld.Name, 4) <> "Per_" Then
    strFieldName = "Per_" & fld.Name & ""
    'rs.Fields (strFieldName)
    'X = "IIf(rec([" & fld.Name & "]) <> 0, Format((rec([Salary]) / rec([" & fld.Name & "])), '$#,###.##'), 0)"
    If FieldExists(EditTable, strFieldName) Then
    Else
        'AltTable = "ALTER TABLE " & EditTable & " ADD COLUMN " & strFieldName & " Double;"
        'CurrentDb.Execute (AltTable)
    End If
        rec.Edit
        X = IIf(rec((fld.Name)) <> 0, Format((rec("Salary") / rec((fld.Name))), "$#,###.##"), 0)
        rec.Fields(strFieldName).Value = X
        rec.Update
  End If
Next fld

End Function
```

Comment: If I may ask, do you know of a good book to use to learn VBA? Just wondering. It would be nice if I could so that maybe I could be more helpful when asking questions. Thanks!! ANyways, Let me see how this works.

Comment: Try one of the SAMS Publishing books.  The only book I ever bought was Access 97 Unleashed.  Other than that, it's been co-workers, trial & error and a whole lotta Google.  :o)

Comment: haha, I've done that whole lotta google thing. Its helped some.. as has this sight. However, this just went way up there.. and I have no way to just "google" it.

Comment: After Testing it, it seems to almost work, but it says that PlayerSal is read only and points to rec.edit... not sure if that is somethings simple on my end, but if it throws everything off, then thanks anyways.

Comment: It worked for me, not sure why your table is read-only.  Like I said, the only thing that needed tweaking was that it would only process the first record in the table, so somewhere there has to be a loop with a rec.movenext so that it goes through every record.  If the tables are actually linked SQL tables then you probably need a key field, other than that I don't know.

Comment: Well it seems to me to work.. other than that.. I can ask another question about the read only thing then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I'm not understanding the question, but you could do something like this:

```
Dim db as database
dim rec as recordset
Dim fld as Field

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("PlayerSal")

For each Fld.name in rec
  If Fld.Name <> "Name" and Fld.Name <> "Salary" then
    Per_" & Fld.Name & " = IIf([" & Fld.Name & "]<>0,Format(([Salary]/[" & Fld.Name & "]),'$#,###.##'),0)
  End If
Next Fld.Name
```

The above is ENTIRELY "aircode" and more than likely won't work out of the box, but hopefully it gives you an idea.

Comment: This is actually close to looking like something I wanted Basically, I wanted to do this and then output it as a query.

Comment: Then add a CreateQuerydef statement and you got it.  :o)

Comment: I did try that.. and it told me, "Variable required, can't assign to this expression." That was in reference to the Fld.name in the For each statement.

Comment: I know there's a way to do that, but I can't think of it off the top of my head and I'm wrapped up in a project at work I gotta get done.  But I had a feeling that part wasn't right.  :o(

Tinker with this: http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/66139-variable-used-recordset-field-name.html

Comment: Thanks for trying man. I appreciate you actually putting help towards what I am getting at. Although I am still confused mostly... but I am better to get better picture of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little more research on this. Looks like you'll need to open a recordset to make sure all your "Per_" fields exist and determine any new fields you need to add. Then you need to close the recordset and run ALTER TABLE statements to create any new fields you need. Then you need to re-open the recordset and update your fields with the value of your formula.

You can probably eliminate the first 2 steps if you just add the new fields manually, but that's how you would have to do it.  If you wanted to eliminate those first 2 steps, you'd end up with something like this:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("tblPlayers")
EditTable = "tblPlayers"

For Each fld In rec.Fields
  If fld.Name <> "PName" And fld.Name <> "Salary" Then
    strFieldName = "Per_" & fld.Name & ""
    X = "IIf([" & fld.Name & "] <> 0, Format(([Salary] / [" & fld.Name & "]), '$#,###.##'), 0)"
    If FieldExists(EditTable, strFieldName) Then
        rec.Edit
        rec.Fields(strFieldName).Value = X
        rec.Update    
    Else
    End If

  End If
Next fld
```

Then you need this function to check if the field exists:

```
Public Function FieldExists(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal fieldName As String) As Boolean
Dim nLen As Long

On Error GoTo Failed
    With DBEngine(0)(0).TableDefs(tableName)
        .Fields.Refresh
        nLen = Len(.Fields(fieldName).Name)
        If nFldLen > 0 Then FieldExists = True
    End With
    Exit Function
Failed:
    If Err.Number = 3265 Then Err.Clear ' Error 3265 : Item not found in this collection.
    FieldExists = False
End Function
```

Comment: So should I put them in the same Module? I ran this in one module after changing tblPlayers to PlayerSal  and I got no errors..only I didn't see anything happen. Still, its a start. Again, I really really really appreciate your help. It seems I found something that might push other people too, which is good I suppose.